# Moving a github repo from windows to mac

Tags: github, repository, repo

I recently have been using a github repo for an intro web design class on my windows laptop, I just got a mac though and am wanting to switch to using my mac to continue with my projects in that repo. Is there a simple way to move the repo to my mac?

I've looked around for a little bit and haven't quite figured out a simple way yet

Comment: Git is designed for this. Have you looked into cloning?